# Check whether button exists Jsoup

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I have a set with urls and I want to check whether each of them contains this button:

[image]

I have tried with the css selector but for some of the pages gives me error, but actually the icon is there ://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
String buttonsCssSelector = ".indepth-content .content a.meta-icon.download";

Elements buttons = doc.select(buttonsCssSelector);
if (!buttons.isEmpty()) {
   // One or more button(s) exist(s) ...
} else {
   // No button found ...
}
```

- [DEMO #1](http://try.jsoup.org/~qKOQREc6HOHbLSs20P9LKxOBVNw)
- [DEMO #2](http://try.jsoup.org/~osrt7Co9KAcah3dEuGMZpcz76ks)

Answer (score 4):

Try to check in source of the page, if it is there then definitely Jsoup selectors  will return the match.

But if the button is being inserted into DOM dynamically by Javascrupt then it will be visible in developer tools in browser but you can't find it in the page downloaded by Jsoup since Jsoup can't do any javascipt execution as browser.

for more information check [panthmJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Comment: Actually, the button isn't inserted with Javascript. The button appear thanks to a CSS rule.